# Appending a pointer to a Qlist

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, append, qlist

this is my first post here!

I'm working on a code that parses Json to fill a struct that I append to a Qlist of tests to run.

My problem is with the payload inside my struct: when I send the first object in my list the payload it is not empty when it should be.

```
struct FrameTest {
    QString protocol;
    QString Length;
    QByteArray *payload;
};

QList<FrameTest> _validTestLists;
FrameTest TxFrame;
```

Code of the JSON parser

```
void Cesa::JsonParser(QJsonObject _ScriptTestObject)
{

TxFrame.protocol = "00";
TxFrame.Length = "00";
TxFrame.payload = new QByteArray();

for(QJsonObject::iterator it = _ScriptTestObject.begin(); it!=_ScriptTestObject.end(); ++it)
{   
    TxFrame.protocol= "00";
    TxFrame.Length = "00";
    TxFrame.payload->clear();

    _CmdObject = _ScriptTestObject.value(key).toObject(); // Get Json object

    if (_CmdObject.contains("Board") && _CmdObject.value("Board") == "Exia")
    {
    QString payload;
    TxFrame.protocol= "03";
    TxFrame.Length = "06";
    payload = QString("%1").arg(obj.value("hopPeriod").toInt(), 2, 16, QChar('0'));
    }

    else if (_CmdObject.contains("Board") && _CmdObject.value("Board") == "Cevee")
    {
    TxFrame.protocol= "03";
    TxFrame.Length = "06";       
    }
_testLists.append(TxFrame);
}

Test(_testLists); // Test with only one object
```

Function for sending via port COM

```
bool Cesa::Test(FrameTest frame)
{
QByteArray txFrame;

/* Transmit command */
txFrame.insert(0, frame.protocol);
txFrame.insert(2, frame.Length);
txFrame.insert(4, *frame.payload);

_comPort->write(QByteArray::fromHex(txFrame));
}
```

I'm a student still learning coding, any help and advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: 1) In your struct you should use `QByteArray` instead of `QByteArray *`. 2) You should check your `txFrame` value before sending. I think that there are not what you expect to have. 3) `QByteArray::fromHex` call looks strange - what you want to do there?

Comment: 1) I'm following another lead but thanks i'll change for a QByteArray - just to let you know i'm not filling a QList anymore instead i'm going with a QMap<QString, QJSonObject> that will hold the name a function (for example : Exia) called later by an executor. When i'm in the Exia function i'll fill a new FrameTest object that will be sent via port COM. 2) My txframe values are correct, why do you think that ? 3) This is some code i got from the student that worked on this project before me : i thought there was a reason why she did this but maybe it's wrong.

Comment: So, you wrote a code and you don't know why you did it, and what this code is doing. Try to remove anything that you wrote randomly and explain to yourself each line of code. Then you will find your mistake.